# How do I reference a path (URL) in Django? But this path is not in the base app, but in another app

Tags: django, url, path

In the base app, which I call it "mywebsite" (the one that contains the settings of the django project), has the urls.py file. But I do not want to reference this file, I want to reference a urls.py in another app, which I call it "account".

For the base file, I would reference as {% url'login' %}, for example. How do I reference to the other one?
Maybe {% account.url 'login' %}?

I tried  {% account.url 'login' %} and {% account/url 'login' %}

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just added to the base urls.py file: `path('account', include("account.urls"))`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already answered your question, but with no further details or explanations. I'll provide the context needed.

---

You have a project package. This folders contains files that affect all the application (the website, not just an app). Inside we have the following files: settings, wsgi, asgi and urls.

In the urls.py (also called URLconf module) file you control the routing of your application, that is, the *[mapping between URL path expressions to Python functions (your views)](https://mapping%20between%20URL%20path%20expressions%20to%20Python%20functions%20(your%20views).)*.

The Django frameworks [knows where to look up for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) file because it's stablished in the settings.py file:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'
```

This is the process (from the docs)

1. Django determines the root URLconf module to use. Ordinarily, this is the value of the ROOT_URLCONF setting...
2. Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable urlpatterns. This should be a sequence of django.urls.path() and/or django.urls.re_path() instances.
3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info.
4. Once one of the URL patterns matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a Python function (or a class-based view)...

But you also have apps, besides the project package. Each app can also have a URLconf module (app/urls.py).

To Django to know the routing to this apps, you have to include them in the global urls.py file (from the project package).

### Finally, the answer:

How do you do it? With the [include()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#include) function.
As you mentioned in your own answer, the code is:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("account.urls")),
]
```

You're including the accounts paths into the global URLconf module.
So when the user types `www.your-domain.com/` he will access the `accounts` app routes.

If instead you did like below, the user should type: `www.your-domain.com/accounts/`.

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include("account.urls")),
]
```